# Using the Uniform Cauchy Criterion theorem

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(f_n)$ is defined, continuous on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on this open interval.
Then $c \in [a,b]$ and $(f_n(c))$ converge $(f'_n)$ and converge uniformly on $(a,b)$ respectively.

How can I prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

I know by uniform cauchy criterion, $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on this set if we can find some $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $m, n \geq N$ and all $x \in a$

But we are only given that there is a single point $f_n(c)$ where it is uniformly convergent, nothing about the entire interval $[a,b]$

Comment: In fact even more is true: not only do the $(f_n)$ converge uniformly, the derivative of the uniform limit is the uniform limit of the $(f_n')$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f_n(x) - f_m(x) = [(f_n - f_m)(x) - (f_n - f_m)(c)]+(f_n - f_m)(c).$$

Use the MVT on the difference in brackets.

Comment: So we would get:

$$ f'_n(c) - f'_m(c) = \frac{(f_n(x) - f_m(x)) - (f_n(c) - f_m(c)) + (f_n(c) - f_m(c))}{x-c}$$

Then, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n \geq N$ 
$$|f'_n(c) - f'_m(c)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing. Don't we get $f_n(x) - f_m(x) = (f_n-f_m)'(d_x)\cdot (x-c) + (f_n-f_m)(c)?$

Comment: zhigan, is that you?